# UIView that loaded from nib files , can i set the owner to the view it self?

Tags: ios, xib, nib

the most common method to init is

`UIView *rootView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyRootView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]`;

and in my case , self is refer to a view controller , but i have to set the owner to the view itself ,because there is many outlet between .m and .xib , how to do with this situations?

Comment: not getting your question explain it properly.

Comment: the problem is that in the above loadNibNamed  ,I have to set a uiview's xib 's file owner to a view controller(because i use this view in a view controller) , this cause  many outlet connection crashed ( because the outlet is defined in custom view class ,not a view controller class) .

Comment: you need to set a uiview's xib 's file owner to a view class (not to view controller).

Comment: and in the code set owner to nil?

Comment: Create Custom UIView.. Set identifier to it in storyboard. and assign this class to Your rootViewControllers view. and set "MyRootView" to your RootViewController as a storyboard identifier.

Comment: What happen you have not replied.

Comment: I did not use storyboard , just a viewcontrolller , view , and a view xib, i have just set xib's owner to controller , xib's view class to custom view class , and make a view connection between controller and xib's view , seems not working -_-

Comment: i think you doing something wrong.

Comment: maybe , i'll write a small demo first to test it :) thanks Ashok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a init method in your view.m class like:

```
- (id)initWithNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName{
     NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:nil options:nil];
     self = [nibContents lastObject];
     if(self){

        //do your code here
      }
     return self;
 }
```

and call this method from viewcontroller. Connect view to view xib.

Comment: Add a init method is not as convinent as create a category for the `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks stack overflow  , there is already a perfect solution for this kind of  problem . 
https://github.com/PaulSolt/CompositeXib
the key is to  call the loadNibNamed in the custom view 's implementation ,not in the controller that create the view.

Comment: I thinks it's a different approaching~ in the example codes in the link , we don't  have to do anything to mix controllers and views. controllers are controllers , views are views . no view's owner are controllers . But still thanks a lot for your great help:) @AshokLondhe

Comment: its ok but i have also told you that.

Comment: I think maybe you told me to the same thing in storyboarding project:) But I can't get it because i don't use storyboard much:)